# Is it possible to change cell color conditionaly in datatool?

Tags: datatool

I have a .csv which is something like this:

```
N,A,B
64,50,64
128,128,120
```

Reading it with:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
    \DTLloaddb{mytable}{mytable.csv}% Load CSV data
    \centering
    \resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    N & A & B \\ \midrule
    \DTLforeach{mytable}{%
      \Nscol=N,
      \AUcol=A,
      \Bcol=B%
    }{%
      \Nscol & \AUcol & \Bcol \\
    }
    \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{table}
```

I would like to conditionally change the color of **each cell**, something like:

```
If A<N 
  textcolor{red}{\Acol}
else
  textcolor{green}{\Acol}
```

It that even possible? I saw there are functions to conditionally check first, last and odd rows but not specifically for each cell.

Thanks for the help.